# CSS3 trick to cut out div from center like 'V' shape

Tags: css

I want to cut out my div element from center like a 'V' shape using CSS3.
I hope someone can help me out with this.
So my designer created a design but something like this :

http://prntscr.com/hpa44s

Does anyone have an idea how to create this in css3?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Found a link that helped me solve it.

```
BODY{
    background: url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5506/9699081016_ba090f1238_h.jpg) 0 -100px;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}

#test {
    height: 101px; /* tweak for ipad */
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
}

#test::before {
    z-index: -1;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: -8px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 16px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-40deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-40deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-40deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-40deg);
    transform: skew(-40deg);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 4px 8px #000;
}

#test::after {
    z-index: -1;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 16px;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform: skew(40deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(40deg);
    -o-transform: skew(40deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(40deg);
    transform: skew(40deg);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 8px #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hCrw/8/